# Why applying seq on a LazySeq returns ChunkedCons?

Tags: clojure

```
(class (range 10))
;=> clojure.lang.LazySeq

(class (seq (range 10))
;=> clojure.lang.ChunkedCons
```

From my understanding, LazySeq is already an sequence, since:

```
(seq? (range 10))
;=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I have an answer.

That's because using `seq` enforces the evaluation of the first element of `LazySeq`. Because `seq` returns `nil` when the collection & sequence is empty, it has to eval the element to decide that.

That's the exactly reason why `rest` is lazier than `next`, because `(next s)` is just `(seq (rest s))`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon your answer (and because comments don't support new lines):

```lisp
user=> (def r (range 10))
#'user/r
user=> (realized? r)
false
user=> (class r)
clojure.lang.LazySeq
user=> (def r2 (rest r))
#'user/r2
user=> (realized? r2)
ClassCastException clojure.lang.ChunkedCons cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPending  clojure.core/realized? (core.clj:6607)
user=> (class r2)
clojure.lang.ChunkedCons
user=> (realized? r)
true
```